# UPDATE AND SELECT INSIDE THE SAME TRANSACTION

Tags: mysql, transaction, acid

I have a transaction that updates a table and then does a SELECT check on that table that was changed, but the data does not follow the update made by the previous UPDATE, there is something I should read or know for the SELECT pull the most current data from the table, or even something I can do to change the behavior of the transaction in this regard?

Comment: I think it would be worth it for you to share the SQL code you're running.